# Derivation of equation for Kendall's $\tau$ for a Frank copula

Tags: copula, integral, kendall-tau

I am trying to prove the equation for Kendall's tau given in Nelsen (1986). In Section 3 , Equation 3.1 is a general form for any copula. Under the case of Frank,

$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}C_\theta(u,v)=\frac{\theta^u(\theta^v-1)}{\theta-1+(\theta^u-1)(\theta^v-1)}$,

also

$\frac{\partial}{\partial v}C_\theta(u,v)=\frac{\theta^v(\theta^u-1)}{\theta-1+(\theta^u-1)(\theta^v-1)}$.

Thus we can obtain the formula of $\tau$ by

$\tau=1-4\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\theta^u\theta^v(\theta^u-1)(\theta^v-1)}{\{\theta-1+(\theta^u-1)(\theta^v-1)\}^2}dudv=1+\frac{4}{-log\theta}\{\frac{1}{-log\theta}\int_{0}^{-log\theta}\frac{t}{e^t-1}dt-1\}$

I tried several methods to prove that the LHS is equal to the RHS. I think it may need a Jacobian transformation, but it seems not so easy. Can anyone give some suggestions?

**Ref.** Nelsen, R. B. (1986). Properties of a one-parameter family of bivariate distributions with specified marginals. Communications in statistics-Theory and methods, 15(11), 3277-3285.

Comment: Can you say on which page Nelsen states $\tau=1-4\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\theta^u\theta^v(\theta^u-1)(\theta^v-1)}{\{\theta-1+(\theta^u-1)(\theta^v-1)\}^2}dudv=1+\frac{4}{-log\theta}\{\int_{0}^{-log\theta}\frac{t}{e^t-1}dt-1\}$, please? I don't see that exact expression anywhere (I am not saying the expression is incorrect, just having trouble verifying that Nelsen actually states it in that way)

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Thank you! It was my fault that I didn't write the question in detal. I will modify the question.